# Database Migration Service for MySQL (GCP): "Error importing data: failed to run mysqldump: import err = , mysqldump error = exit status 2..."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, database-migration, google-cloud-sql

I need some help here.

I'm trying to migrate a large database (500+ GB) using Google's Database Migration job.

I think I did all the settings correctly but I'm keeping getting the same error message:

> DUMP_STAGE(FAILED): failed to run mysqldump: import err = ,
> mysqldump error = exit status 2, stderr: mysqldump: [Warning] Using a
> password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Here's the database replica instance flags I'm using:

```
log_bin_trust_function_creators   on
event_scheduler                   on
character_set_server              utf8
sql_mode                          STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
                                  ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
net_read_timeout                  7200
net_write_timeout                 7200
max_allowed_packet                1073741824
general_log                       on
read_buffer_size                  2147479552
```

I don't know what to do. I don't know if I'm missing something. Any idea?

I can give more information if needed.

Comment: Your mysqldump has all the requirements [requested](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external#export)?

Comment: I'm not using the dump file. I'm using the new Database Migration Service for MySQL. It's generating the dump file automatically.

Comment: I think that in this case its better open a [GCP support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs#how_to_sign_up) in order that you receive further advice about this issue